# Intellij IDEA Android Resource Jump to Definition XML File instead of R.java

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, android-resources

In Android Studio, if I reference a resource in code, for example `R.string.some_sample_string` or `R.layout.activity_main`, and I jump to definition (CMD + B on OS X) it will take me to the line in the appropriate `strings.xml` file or the appropriate layout xml file for `activity_main.xml`.

Lately I've been using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate for Android development. When I jump to definition in IDEA it brings me to the declaration of the class in the generated `R.class` file instead of the resource XML files.

Is there a way to make IDEA behave like Android Studio and jump to the xml files instead of the java class declarations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the issue here was actually my project file.
On our team, we use our own project generation with our monorepo to automate selecting which files should be indexed by IntelliJ. As it turns out this is currently an issue/limitation with our internal automation tool.

It's not a spectacular answer, but if you are encountering a similar issue I would suspect that the project file has been tampered with and that you should either nuke it and create a new one or take it up with anyone who might be doing this similar kind of project manipulation in your team.